# Loading a DLL with LoadLibraryA(path_to_dll) is changing the inherit handle flag (HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT) from 1 to 0 for file descriptors 0, 1, and 2

Tags: c++, go, dll, dlopen, loadlibrary

We have written some functions in golang and a c wrapper on top of that to invoke those functions. We first build golang code to create an archive file and then we build the wrapper code in c to be consumed as a DLL.

After loading this DLL using LoadLibraryA(path_to_dll) in my program I am seeing that the inherit flags for fd 0, 1, and 2 are getting changed from 1 to 0. This does not happen immediately after loading the DLL though. I had added sleep in my code after the load library call and seems like it takes a few milliseconds after loading the library to change the flag values.

I am using GetHandleInformation((HANDLE) sock, &flags) to get the inherit flag value.

Any idea/pointers on what could be causing this? Thanks!

**Updates:**
I was able to find out the exact line in the go code that is flipping the inherit flag values. The global variable reqHandler in below k8sService.go code is causing this. **Any idea why the use of this global variable is flipping the inherit flag values?**

my-lib/k8sService.go (go code)

```
package main

import "C"
import (
    "my-lib/pkg/cmd"
)

func main() {
}

var reqHandler []*cmd.K8sRequest
```

my-lib/pkg/cmd/execute.go

```
import (
    "my-lib/pkg/dto"
)

type K8sRequest struct {
    K8sDetails dto.K8sDetails
}
```

my-lib/pkg/dto/structs.go

```
package dto

// K8sDetails contains all the necessary information about talking to the cluster. Below struct has few more variables.
type K8sDetails struct {
    // HostName of the cluster's API server
    HostName string `json:"hostname"`
    // Port on which the API server listens on to
    Port int `json:"port"`
}
```

We have a C wrapper on top of the above k8sService.go. We first build golang code to create an archive file and then with this archive file and wrapper code in C we build the target DLL. Below is the sample program which loads this DLL and also prints the inherit flag values before and after loading the DLL.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include "wrapper/cWrapper.h"

void printInheritVals() {
        typedef SOCKET  my_socket_t;
        my_socket_t fd0 = _get_osfhandle(0);
        my_socket_t fd1 = _get_osfhandle(1);
        my_socket_t fd2 = _get_osfhandle(2);
        std::cout << "fd0: " << fd0 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "fd1: " << fd1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "fd2: " << fd2 << std::endl;
        
        
        DWORD flags;
        int inherit_flag_0 = -1;
        int inherit_flag_1 = -1;
        int inherit_flag_2 = -1;
        

        if (!GetHandleInformation((HANDLE) fd0, &flags)) {
            std::cout << "GetHandleInformation failed" << std::endl;
        } else {
            inherit_flag_0 = (flags & HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT);
        }

        if (!GetHandleInformation((HANDLE) fd1, &flags)) {
            std::cout << "GetHandleInformation failed" << std::endl;
        } else {
            inherit_flag_1 = (flags & HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT);
        }

        if (!GetHandleInformation((HANDLE) fd2, &flags)) {
            std::cout << "GetHandleInformation failed" << std::endl;
        } else {
            inherit_flag_2 = (flags & HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT);
        }
        
        std::cout << "inherit_flag_0: " << inherit_flag_0 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "inherit_flag_1: " << inherit_flag_1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "inherit_flag_2: " << inherit_flag_2 << std::endl;
}

int main()
{

    printInheritVals(); // In output all flag values are 1
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibraryA(PATH_TO_DLL);
    if (!hGetProcIDDLL) {
        std::cout << "could not load the dynamic library" << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::cout << "Library loaded" << std::endl;
    printInheritVals(); // In output all flag values are 1
    Sleep(1000);
    printInheritVals(); // In output all flag values are 0
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Without looking at the code, one could only speculate. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CristiFati I have added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the **golang.org/x/sys/windows** package. The same issue [used to be in the built-in syscall package as well](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44876#issuecomment-797683021), but it was [fixed in Go 1.17](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/4c8f48ed4f3db0e3ba376e6b7a261d26b41d8dd0).

Something in your project must be importing the golang.org/x version of the package instead of the built-in one, and so the following code executes to initialize the `Stdin`, `Stdout`, and `Stderr` variables:

```
var (
    Stdin  = getStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
    Stdout = getStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    Stderr = getStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE)
)

func getStdHandle(stdhandle uint32) (fd Handle) {
    r, _ := GetStdHandle(stdhandle)
    CloseOnExec(r)
    return r
}
```

The fix for that code would be to remove the `CloseOnExec` call, which is what clears `HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT` on the given file handle.

How to solve that in your project is less clear. I think you can *vendor* `golang.org/x/sys` module in your project, perhaps with a `replace` directive in your go.mod. Apply the fix in your local copy.

Meanwhile, I encourage you to also report the bug. [The documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys#section-readme) instructs you to report the issue on the [main Go project at GitHub](https://github.com/golang/go/issues), prefixing the title with **x/sys**.

Comment: Thanks Rob! I have opened an issue against x/sys as well: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/52498